# filter links on page web by files extensions

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm working on program to extract links from web page and filter them this my code so far using HtmlAgilityPack

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc = hw.Load(txt_url.Text);
        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("a//[@href]"))
        {
            // Get the value of the HREF attribute
            string hrefValue = link.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty);
            listbox1.Items.Add(hrefValue);

        }
```

this code is extracting all links from web page  so my question is how to filter those Urls  by the extension like ".html"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [WebClient.DownloadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the html.

Then use a a regex pattern on the string to capture all the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to do a HTTP GET request and get the response body with the HTML code.

```
//Request HTTP GET

ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Proxy = null;
request.Method = "GET";

WebResponse response;
string html = "";

response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
html = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
response.Close();
```

Then you can parse HTML code with a Regex to extract desired files.